# what exactly is switch preference in android?

Tags: android

I have been through https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/SwitchPreference.html
this link but still I am confused wit what is a "switch preference" in android.
Why exactly is it used? And for what is it used? 
Any example which can show the importance of Switch Preference in android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SwitchPreference is a preference item which gives you a switch - it can either be on or off.

I hope this picture can clarify it for you (taken from Google's Material Design Guidelines):

[image: switchpreference]